# META-INF/persistence.xml could not be found in GWT/Maven project when packaging/deploying to tomcat

Tags: gwt, maven-2, jpa

I am currently working on a GWT project. I have used the GWT webapplicationcreator shell script to create it with the -maven option since I use maven for building it.

So the problem is that when I package the project, using "mvn package", and deploy it to tomcat, it tells me that it can not find out META-INF/persistence.xml even though in my project I have it at the correct location src/main/webapp/META-INF/persistence.xml. I have even extracted the war file to check that it's out there.

> 246 [Thread-38] INFO org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration - Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath

Have you ever experienced this weird behaviour ? Can you help me figure it out ?

thanks a lot guys

Comment: I've expecting this too... how you solve it?

Comment: @caarlos0 : just create a resources packages, i.e "src/main/resources" and put the META-INF/ in it instead of just putting if in the src/main/webapp folder. Don't forget to put the orm.xml and persistence.xml in as well

Comment: actualy I solve this in another way, because my project is multi-module: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252845/maven-submodules-in-eclipse-resources-from-one-module-not-found-in-another

Answer (score 2):

Check persistence.xml is correctly deployed.

See this very useful link:
http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2007/06/where-to-put-persistencexml-in-web-app.html

Comment: Thanks for your response,

I found out the solution. In order for maven to build your gwt project correctly, you should create a resources packages, I mean "src/main/resources" and put the META-INF/ in it instead of just putting if in the src/main/webapp folder directly.
Don't forget to put the orm.xml and persistence.xml in as well.

have fun...