# Maven submodules in eclipse: Resources from one module not found in another

Tags: gwt, maven

I have the following Maven project estruture:

```
Example
-Persistence
-GWTApp
```

The persistence has the persistence.xml in `src/main/resources/META-INF`, and it works fine in unitary tests.

I need to use it in the GWTApp project. So, I add it as depency. like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Persistence</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

With this, I can see and use the persistence classes in my webapp, but, when I run the webproject in eclipse, I got this error:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named exemplo

I think that's because eclipse done this "link" between projects referencing the persistence project in webapp project, instead of using a jar file. Maybe I'm wrong, it's just a guess.

Someone knew how can I fix this?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT

I do more tests, and now I believe thats problem is something just with GWT dev mode and JPA, or something.
I tried to manually copy persistence.xml to `weapp/META-INF` and to `target/project-webapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/META-INF` and the error persist.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you launching the app correctly? https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq#gwt_with_maven

Particularly, note that you have to "mvn war:exploded" to copy your dependencies target/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib

Comment: I found the solution! I mistake one step of configuration, I just config this: `Right-click your project and select Run As > Web Application. The first time you do this, you'll have to select the location of the exploded WAR directory (by default it should be /target/<AppName>-<version>).` and it worked. thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using M2E. If yes, open the "Configure Build Path" dialog for the Persistence project (right-click on the build path, and select the "Build Path" sub-menu).

If you look at the "resources" folder, I suspect that you'll see "Excluded: **"; this prevents Eclipse from copying the files into the local output directory, and also prevents them from being available to dependent projects. Select that line and click "Remove"

I have no idea why M2E does this, and I know there's a preference to disable it, but I just do it manually.

Comment: It was not like this... It was "Excluided: **/*.java"; BTW, I excluded that line... still not working...